# Silverstripe: Member Profile - Update details on Frontend

Tags: php, forms, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to allow users to update their details from a frontend 'dashboard' type of page. I've got the form displaying, but when I click 'Update details', the form redirects to a blank page, and the fields haven't changed. Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
<?php

class MemberProfile extends Page {
    private static $description = 'Page that displays the current user\'s profile';

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        // we don't want the Content editor for this page type
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'Content');
        return $fields;
    }
}

class MemberProfile_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'UpdateDetails'
    );

    public function UpdateDetails() {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('FirstName','First name:')
                    ->setAttribute('value', Member::CurrentUser()->FirstName),
                TextField::create('Surname','Last name:')
                    ->setAttribute('value', Member::CurrentUser()->Surname)
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('saveDetails','Update details')
            )
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function saveDetails($data,$form) {
        $CurrentMember = Member::CurrentMember();
        $CurrentMember->FirstName = $data['FirstName'];
        $CurrentMember->Surname = $data['Surname'];
        $form->saveInto($CurrentMember);
        $CurrentMember->write();
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be a dev/build is needed to include the static allowed actions... that is normally what it is for me.

However my main answer would be to use this module for management of user profiles, it allows for many customisations and will save you alot of time....

https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-memberprofiles

"A new page type is added in the CMS called a "Member Profile Page". This allows you to create a page that allows users to register and/or manage their profile. Registration can be enabled or disabled in the "Behaviour" tab."

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you help me add other fields to the 'gridfield' in the profile page content settings? I'd like to have phone number and address displayed on the front end (and allow the user to update them). @Barry

Comment: These are all configurable through a gui when using the above module.

Comment: thanks. I actually figured it out before I saw this response. For anyone who wants to know...

Click the "Profile" tab on the "Member Profile" page settings in the CMS admin. If you want extra fields displayed on the member profile, create an extension of the "Member" class, run a dev/build, and they'll show up there.